# Rational cohomology of $S$-arithmetic groups over function fields and Gauss-Bonnet

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-cohomology, buildings, function-fields

I have a question on the ranks of rational cohomology groups of
$S$-arithmetic groups over function fields. To fix the situation, $G$
is a simple Chevalley group of rank $r$, $k=\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite
field, and $C$ 
a smooth affine curve over $k$. Then $k[C]\cong\mathcal{O}_{k(C),S}$
is a ring of $S$-integers, and $\Gamma=G(k[C])$ is an $S$-arithmetic
group. From Harder's work (G. Harder. Die Kohomologie
$S$-arithmetischer Grupen über Funktionenkörpern. Invent. math. 42,
(1977), 135-175), we know that the only non-trivial rational
cohomology groups of $\Gamma$ are in degrees $0$ and $r|S|$. Moreover,
in loc.cit. Harder states two things:

1. the cohomology in degree $r|S|$ is the multiplicity of a special
   representation in the discrete spectrum of $L^2(\prod_{v\in
       S}G(K_v)/\Gamma)$
2. there might be a Gauss-Bonnet formula providing a relation
   between the rank of $\operatorname{H}^{r|S|}(\Gamma,\mathbb{Q})$ and
   the volume of $\prod_{v\in S}G(K_v)/\Gamma$.

Actually, I have several questions about this. Generally, I would like
to know if there exist formulas to compute the rank of
$\operatorname{H}^{r|S|}(\Gamma,\mathbb{Q})$ in terms of arithmetic or
cohomological data of the curve $C$.

First, are there explicit formulas for the multiplicity of the special
representation as in point 1 above? I have only a vague idea about
representation theory, so I would not know where to look and even not
recognize the answer when I see it. Can somebody explain about the
multiplicity statement and point me to some relevant literature?

Second, Harder only mentions it might be a harder question if there is
a Gauss-Bonnet formula as in the number field case. I know that there
is another paper of Harder discussing this Gauss-Bonnet formula in
number field cases. I have also seen formulas reminiscent of
Gauss-Bonnet in papers of Harder-Narasimhan on vector bundles and
Tamagawa numbers. The questions are: what would be the precise
Gauss-Bonnet formula in this setting, and is it written and proved
somewhere? Is there an expression of the volume of $\prod_{v\in
  S}G(K_v)/\Gamma$ in more simplicial terms, using  the
quotient of the Bruhat-Tits building on which $\Gamma$ acts? How could
this volume be computed in terms of arithmetic or cohomological data
of the curve $C$, as mentioned above?

Finally, some context why I am interested in this. I looked at a
specific example, where $C$ is an elliptic curve minus a $k$-rational
point. I think I can compute the dimension of
$\operatorname{H}^2(\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q[C]),\mathbb{Q})$  in this
case: it is $q^3$, so depends only on the base field $\mathbb{F}_q$
and is independent of the elliptic curve. So the above two questions
can be stated more specifically: is there a representation-theoretic
explanation of this rank (I notice that the Steinberg representation
of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is of dimension $q^3$ and I can
see some connection to this)? How would the computation of the rank
follow from Gauss-Bonnet and cohomological data of the elliptic
curve? Can any of these two approaches explain why the rank is
independent of the curve? (Or maybe, do representation-theoretic
interpretations resp. Gauss-Bonnet formulas imply that my dimension
computation is wrong?)